# Is passing too much data as argument a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was wondering whether a way we pass arguments to the function means something. Let's say that I have a function responsible for checking if a user is introduced basing on its inner name object.

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: {
    first: string;
    last: string;
  }
}
```

Which of function usage is the best?

**No. 1**

```
function isUserIntroduced(user: User): boolean {
  return user.name.first && user.name.last;
}
```

We pass here the whole user object but we need only its inner name data so it looks like the worse solution because the rest of the data (imagine that User is much bigger than above interface) isn't needed.

**No. 2**

```
function isUserIntroduced(name: UserName): boolean {
  return name.first && name.last;
}
```

UserName is an interface for the name object in User interface (just to make it a bit shorter). Now we pass only the data we need, right? But in every place we call this function, the call is a bit longer itself `this.isUserIntroduced(user.name)` instead of `this.isUserIntroduced(user)`. The question is also if the function's name is now appropriate to its purpose. Well it checks if user is introduced but in fact it operates only around the name. So the best name for it should be "isTheNameValid" or something.

**No. 3**

```
function isUserIntroduced({name}: User): boolean {
  return name.first && name.last;
}
```

This in my opinion is the best. Calling this function is as short as in No. 1 but inside the function we have an access only to the data that we need. Unfortunately after compile the code for No. 3 looks like this:

```
function x(_a) {
    var name = _a.name;

    return name.first && name.last;
}
```

so in fact even if we don't have an access to the rest of data, it still exists in memory.

Comment: I'd say stop worrying and in general use both `isUserNameIntroduced` and `function isUserIntroduced(user) { return isUserNameIntroduced(user.name); }`. Then drop either one if you think it's too much detail.

Comment: Depends on the application, doesn't matter in almost all cases. If you offer an API to the outside for other developers, the interface should be decided on at another level anyways and would be clear already (and this question wouldn't arise, as the signature of the function is already decided). If there is no API, do whatever feels best.

Comment: "*after compile the code*" - is no longer interesting. The source needs to be readable, the rest doesn't matter. "*it still exists in memory*" - it always does. And doesn't matter either - notice that function calls don't copy large chunks of data around, you're only passing object references.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a matter of opinion and specifics of your usage so it's not a great fit for SO

Comment: Its all a reference anyway, when you send the entire object you are merely sending a reference to a single object in memory.

Comment: Actually you're right. I've completely forgotten about the reference. So if it is how it is, the best scenario for me is the third one when we pass the whole object and inside the function we have an access only to the fields we're interested in. Thanks to it the function's name is appropriate to its purpose (because it is about user and we pass a user) and the call is shorter than when we'd have to pass nested data. Thank you all guys.